# How to put because sign( ∵ ) on latex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Latex does not recognize the sign '∵'.

Comment: Use `\because` from `amssymb`

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for `\because` from the `amssymb` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\because$
\end{document}
```

[image]

When in doubt of a symbol I'd reccomend looking at [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/117125)